VScode не видит заглавную кириллицу
При попытке запуска файла с расширением .py (и других файлов в консоли VSCode) в терминале появляется следующее сообщение:
& : Имя "C:/Users/дмин/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe" не распознано как имя 
командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания и 
мени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:2 знак:3

+ & C:/Users/дмин/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe c: ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:/Users/дмин/A...n312/python.exe:String) [], Com  
   mandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

И да, имя пользователя — Администратор.

Это не vscode, а powershell.

Удалить модуль psreadline и установить заново
